# Latin Perfect Tense and romance languages particularly Portuguese

Tags: classical-latin, meaning, medieval-latin, language-evolution, vulgar-latin

How did the perfect tense evolve in each romance language?

For example is the Preterito Perfeito functionally equivalent to the Latin Perfect Tense?

Heri dormivi.

Ontem dormi.

Ayer dormi.

Hier j'ai dormi. (I think Passe Simple would work better)

Ieri ho dormito (actually I believe passato remoto works better since I am definetely awake when I say that I slept yesterday and as such I am not in the same state)

I see a lot of differences in the romance languages. Actually the Portuguese preterito perfeito composto isn't the present perfect but the present perfect continuous (it implies an iterative aspect).

Comment: You seem to have two questions here. Both are interesting, but I recommend asking them separately. Can you edit this one to focus on just one? // I imagine I am not the only user here who has never studied Portuguese grammar but would probably get an idea pretty quickly if you could provide a couple of example sentences, possibly with both Latin and Portuguese versions. Examples will also clarify what the question is exactly.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta It is just one question. How did the perfect tense evolve in each romance language. The "first one" is only introductory and super-specific. Just an example.

Comment: Oh, I see. That wasn't clear to me from reading the question. Either way, the question could use some fleshing out and examples. I imagine a complete story of the evolution of the Romance perfect tense could fill a book.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Better now?